# How to add a user that accept any password as a valid password?

Tags: security, login, pam, passwd, login-manager

**How to add a user that accept any password as a valid password?**

PS:

- I am aware of the security issue. The user will have a very restricted access (as the `guest` user in Ubuntu).
- related question: [How to log into another user if the entered password is wrong?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860002/how-to-log-into-another-user-if-the-entered-password-is-wrong)

Comment: look at `/etc/pam.d/passwd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This configuration was tested on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS Server. Modify `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`.

```
# [...]
auth [success=2 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user = the_username
# [...]
auth requisite pam_deny.so
# [...]
auth required pam_permit.so
# [...]
```

- The `success=x` portion tells PAM to skip `x` rules on success.
- Substitute the real username for `the_username`, above.

So, all users first try to authenticate with `pam_unix.so`, which requires a correct username and password in order to succeed. If authentication succeeds with `pam_unix.so`, then proceed to  `pam_permit.so`. That's the default behavior.

If authentication failed with `pam_unix.so`, proceed to `pam_succeed_if.so`, which succeeds whenever a user enters the username of `the_username`, using whatever password was entered. If both `pam_unix.so` and `pam_succeed_if.so` fail, then proceed to `pam_deny.so`; otherwise, proceed to `pam_permit.so`.

A word of caution: be very careful on a live system because it's easy to make a mistake and lock yourself out, probably requiring a fix via rescue media.