# How to configure SSHD to allow users to ssh without password or public key?

Tags: linux, sshd

I just want to allow one user to be public, i.e. let people log in without typing a password or having to setup a public key. This is to create an open SSH app. It should be simple but it seems to be not working, this is my sshd_config:

```
UsePAM no
Match User app
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        # PermitTTY no
        PermitEmptyPasswords yes
        AuthenticationMethods none
        ForceCommand myapp
```

When I try to ssh as client I am prompted for password:

```
app@192.168.0.8's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I already tried some variations without luck.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with OpenSSH, but you can do it with some custom code. See [this example](https://github.com/kryptographik/ShuSSH) using Python's [`paramiko`](https://www.paramiko.org/) module, or [this one](https://github.com/shazow/ssh-chat) written in Go.

Answer (score 2):

#### Preliminary notes

1. Start an elevated shell (`sudo -i`) and keep it open. In case something goes wrong, use the elevated shell to revert changes.
2. Make copies (`sudo cp -a …`) of the files you are going to modify.
3. At the end make sure you are able to log in anew and to authenticate to `sudo` anew. Only then close the elevated shell.

---

#### Solution – part 1: `/etc/ssh/sshd.conf`

Configure your `sshd` to use PAM and its keyboard-interactive authentication instead of password authentication managed by `sshd` itself. The simplest way is to do this unconditionally for all users. In `/etc/ssh/sshd.conf`:

```
UsePAM yes
PasswordAuthentication no
KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
#...
```

Notes:

- The first obtained value for each parameter is used.
- `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` is a deprecated alias for `KbdInteractiveAuthentication`, so make sure there is no `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no` earlier in the file.
- `PasswordAuthentication` and `KbdInteractiveAuthentication` can be placed after `Match User …`, so you can have keyboard-interactive authentication for user `app` and usual password authentication for everyone else; but `UsePAM` is global. The snippet may look like this:

  ```
  UsePAM yes
  Match User app
        PasswordAuthentication no
        KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
  Match All
  PasswordAuthentication yes
  KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
  ```

Restart or reload `sshd` after modifying the file (e.g. in Debian: `sudo systemctl reload ssh.service`).

---

#### Solution – part 2: `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` or `/etc/pam.d/sshd`

Two methods:

- If you want to always automatically authenticate user `app` then modify `/etc/pam.d/commmon-auth`.
- If you want to automatically authenticate user `app` only if `sshd` is involved then modify `/etc/pam.d/sshd` but not `/etc/pam.d/commmon-auth`.

In practice you should modify either `/etc/pam.d/commmon-auth` or `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. Modifying them both is excessive.

---

##### Solution - part 2a: `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`

To configure PAM to always automatically authenticate user `app`, add a line containing `pam_succeed_if.so` before the (already existing) line containing `pam_unix.so` in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`. The file should look like this:

```
# [...]
auth [success=2 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user = app
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok
# [...]
auth requisite pam_deny.so
# [...]
auth required pam_permit.so
# [...]
```

This is a modified method from [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330152/108618), it's explained there. I placed `pam_succeed_if` first, so user `app` is authenticated without being processed (prompted for password) by `pam_unix`.

This will automatically authenticate user `app` no matter what tool requests authentication; e.g. other users will be able to `su app` freely. If you want to automatically authenticate user `app` only when `sshd` requests it then you need to modify `/etc/pam.d/sshd` instead; keep reading.

---

##### Solution - part 2b: `/etc/pam.d/sshd`

To configure PAM to automatically authenticate user `app` when `sshd` is involved, add two lines before (already existing) `@include common-auth` in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. The beginning of the file should look like this:

```
# [...]

auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user != app
auth sufficient pam_permit.so

# Standard Un*x authentication.
@include common-auth

# [...]
[...]
```